# Nginx + django return 404 when first configurated

Tags: python, django, nginx, http-status-code-404

When I visit "localhost/media/media.png" it returns 404 but the file already exists in the folder. How can I solve the problem?

I am learning Python and I want to build a website with nginx, uwsgi and django so I read the official tutorial on https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html?highlight=django to configurate the my web server. But I got into trouble when I "Configure nginx for your site". The tutorial doesn't seem to work on my computer.

python version: 2.7.15rc1
nginx version: 1.14.0(Ubuntu)
django version: 1.11.20

```
# cs_community_site_nginx.conf

upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 10.**.**.231; #
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /mnt/c/Users/duyu0/Documents/starfire/cs_community/cs_community_server/cs_community_site/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /mnt/c/Users/duyu0/Documents/starfire/cs_community/cs_community_server/cs_community_site/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /mnt/c/Users/duyu0/Documents/starfire/cs_community/cs_community_server/cs_community_site/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot the pass the port on your link: localhost/media/media.png so be in fact http://localhost:8000/media/media.png or http://localhost:8001/media/media.png

Comment: It works! Thanks! :D @HigorRossato